# public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) does not react

Tags: android, webview

public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
does not react.
My build gradle :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "*****"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

}
```

This method not work, not react absolutely:

```
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request){
    System.out.println("blabla");
}
```

This method work:

```
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url){
    System.out.println("blabla");
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

method `shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)` was added in API 21,
method `shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url)` was added in API 11
see [doc from d.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest))

in your `build.gradle`,
'minSdkVersion 14' means that your app could be run on api 14 or later. but that is not means that you can use higher api method for that.

What is your testing environment?
does your android phone supports Lollipop(API 21)?
I think your phone might be support api 20 or less. that is why a method doesn't work.

solution?
Don't use `shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)`
OR
set `minSdkVersion 14` to `minSdkVersion 21`

Comment: @Andreyua Could you accept my answer? If you thought it was helpful. please.